# the usual Use of uninitialised value of size 4

Tags: c, image-processing, initialization

I'm really struggling to find what's wrong here. Please help.

In main, I declare (width and length are known):

```
    short** the_image;
    print_image_array(the_image,image_width,image_length);
```

where

```
print_image_array(the_image, image_width, image_length)
    short** the_image;
    long image_width, image_length;
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < image_length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < image_width; j++)
            printf("%d ", the_image[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And from valgrind, I get the message:

```
==2423==    at 0x80490D2: print_image_array
==2423==    by 0x80491F3: main
==2423==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2423==    at 0x804911E: main
==2423== 
==2423== Invalid read of size 2
==2423==    at 0x80490DB: print_image_array
==2423==    by 0x80491F3: main
==2423==  Address 0x1e5ec381 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Why is the image not initialized? I also tried declaring

```
short the_image[length][width];
```

but no luck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can never reference to the the_image

Comment: I hope `print_image_array` is a legacy function. If you defined a function K&R style, repent and better your ways. C has prototypes now.

Comment: "Why is the image not initialized?" -- We don't know why you didn't initialize it. Why do you expect it to be initialized when there's no initializer or assignment to it?

Comment: Between the declaration of `the_image`, and the call to `print_image_array`, how do you allocate it?

Comment: @hetepeperfan Why? It's valid C89.

Comment: @JimBalter I'll remove the comment, I learned C on a much later stage, I've not seen a function declared this way.

Comment: @hetepeperfan  It's the C equivalent of Chaucer's English.

Comment: @Barmar Chaucer's English is uninterpretable by most modern English speakers, whereas a large fraction of C programmers are familiar with K&R declarations, and there's still legacy code that uses them.

Comment: @JimBalter OK, Shakespearean English -- intelligible, but it sounds weird :)

Comment: @Barmar A much better analogy, forsooth!

Comment: @DanielFischer: I also tried allocating by `short the_image[length][width]`. didn't work...

Comment: First, you're mixing up allocation and initialization ... except for file-scope variables, allocation doesn't initialize unless there's an initializer. On top of that, print_image_array expects a pointer to an array of pointers, not a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `print_image_array()` you need to initialize the array:

```
the_image = malloc(image_length * sizeof(short*));
for (int i = 0; i < image_length; i++) {
    the_image[i] = malloc(image_width * sizeof(short));
}
```

And if you want to print something sensible, you also need to fill this in with actual values. Otherwise, you'll just get whatever random garbage happens to be in the heap.

You can't allocate the array with

```
short the_image[image_length][image_width]
```

because arrays don't carry their dimensions with them in C.  `print_image_array()` declares `the_image` as `short**`, which is just a pointer to a pointer, not a two-dimensional array with a declared width.  So it requires the parameter to be an array of pointers.

Since C99, you can also do this:

```
void print_image_array(short the_image[image_length][image_width], int image_width, int image_length);
```

This function declaration would be compatible with the above array declaration, but it's not compatible with the array of pointers that I initialized in my code. You have to pick one way or the other, and ensure that the function and caller agree.

Comment: Note that the OP also tried `short the_image[length][width];`

Comment: That doesn't work because `print_image_array()` doesn't know the array dimensions. So it treats it as an array of pointers, not a 2-d array.

Comment: how do you suggest, i allocate and pass it?

Comment: I know why it doesn't work  (it's the wrong type) ... I meant to suggest that you add an explanation to your answer (SO favors all elements of an answer to be in the answer, not just in comments).

Comment: Added more explanation, as well as showing the C99 way to accept multi-dimensional array parameters.